# Is there a GUI for DNS lookups

Tags: domain-name-system, graphical-user-interface

I am looking for a graphical interface to interogate a local server about the DNS entries it has. Basically I want a graphical [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Information_Groper) / [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) environment similar to [Zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/).

I would also prefer it to be runnable on an Ubuntu desktop.

I want to use it for testing out a DNS server.

Comment: After researching for the nicer application for your question, you changed it 360 degrees. If you want it to run on Linux (and Zenmap does just that), and you want similar to Zenmap, what is wrong with?

Comment: Zenmap is for penetration testing, not for looking up dns entries.

Answer (score 2):

[GResolver](http://jodrell.net/projects/gresolver) is a nice graphical tool for DNS queries for linux and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try [gnome-network](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-network/index.shtml)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://dnstools.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://network-tools.com/nslook/

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you have :

- [DNSDataView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_records_viewer.html)

For Linux :

- [gnome-network](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-network)